# Webservice client, should i keep service or port instance?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, cxf

I am developing web service client with `cxf-codegen-plugin` and it is generating class `MyService extends Service` for client part.
My question now is: when I am creating client, should my `MyService` object be created each time I want to send request or keep it and each time create Port? Or can I keep Port as well? What is the best way to make client?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping the Port around is definitely the best performing option, but keep in mind the thread safety aspects:

http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-AreJAXWSclientproxiesthreadsafe%3F

Answer (score 0):

To create `Service` class each time the request is sent would be very inefficient way. Proper way to create web service client would be on first application start up. For e.g. I call web services from web application and using `ServletContextListener` to initialize web service. CXF web service client can be created like this:

```
private SecurityService proxy;

/**
 * Security wrapper constructor.
 *
 * @throws SystemException if error occurs
 */
public SecurityWrapper()
        throws SystemException {
    try {
        final String username = getBundle().getString("wswrappers.security.username");
        final String password = getBundle().getString("wswrappers.security.password");
        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(
                        username,
                        password.toCharArray());
            }
        });
        URL url = new URL(getBundle().getString("wswrappers.security.url"));
        QName qname = new QName("http://hltech.lt/ws/security", "Security");
        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
        proxy = service.getPort(SecurityService.class);
        Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider) proxy).getRequestContext();
        requestContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, url.toString());
        requestContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, username);
        requestContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);
        Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        headers.put("Timeout", Collections.singletonList(getBundle().getString("wswrappers.security.timeout")));
        requestContext.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error occurred in security web service client initialization", e);
        throw new SystemException("Error occurred in security web service client initialization", e);
    }
}
```

And on application start up I create this class' instance and set it to application context. Also there is a nice way to create client using spring. Take a look here: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: so you keep proxy (Port) as initialized WS