# CXF Apache WSDL2Java set endpoint

Tags: apache, cxf, endpoint, wsdl2java

In the beginning I have to warn that I'm not familar with web services, I want to simply generate what I need, and learn the basics of usage.

I recived .wsdl and .xsd files (stored localy). I have generated java code using Apache CXF WSDL2Java tool (I have generated a client). I also have an endpoint (as url without '?WSDL' on the end - whatever this endding means). How can I set this endpoint?

If I use:

```
Blachblach_Service ss = new Blachblach_Service(new URL(recived_url));
Blachblach port = ss.getBlachblachSOAP();
```

I get an exception. When I use soapUI to send XMLs to web services, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you need to initialize your web service client. See my answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428849/webservice-client-should-i-keep-service-or-port-instance/11487791#11487791) how to make this work.

`?WSDL` ending means that you can see the web service WSDL file in your browser, you can access the web service through `SOAP` protocol by providing it with some valid request.

If you need to create your web service client using `Spring`. [Here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html) is very good example how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes usually we set params like end point URL on Service class object and retrieve port from it. and from port we invoke web service methods. can you please give details of exception you are getting?