# Weblogic stuck thread in JAX-WS Client

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, jax-ws

My web application front end runs on its own dedicated weblogic server. My webservices are deployed on a different server machine, on weblogic.

I consume webservices this way:

```
URL url = new URL("http://xxx:7001/corpevent/rightsservice?wsdl");
QName qname = new QName("http://corpevent.service.org/", "rightsservice");

Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
RightsIssueService ri = service.getPort(org.service.corpevent.RightsIssueService.class);
ri.callMethod();
```

It works fine, but sometimes I get stuck thread issues. I have tried to figure out how to stop it from happening but everything I've tried hasn't worked so far.

Here is the stack trace:

```
"[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '28' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" Id=138 BLOCKED on org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext@bbec059 owned by "[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" Id=67

  at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.newContextState(JAXBContext.java:270)

  - blocked on org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext@bbec059

  at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.refreshMetadata(JAXBContext.java:255)

  at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.jrCheckReload(JAXBContext.java)

  at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.createMarshaller(JAXBContext.java)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.db.toplink.JAXBContextWrapper$1.newInstance(JAXBContextWrapper.java:85)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.db.toplink.JAXBContextWrapper$1.newInstance(JAXBContextWrapper.java:82)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.db.toplink.ObjectPool.allocate(ObjectPool.java:65)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.db.toplink.JAXBBond.marshal(JAXBBond.java:128)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBHeader.writeTo(JAXBHeader.java:200)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeToBodyStart(AbstractMessageImpl.java:178)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:191)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.MessageWrapper.writeTo(MessageWrapper.java:226)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:144)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:242)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:225)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:145)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:110)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:463)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:191)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:92)

  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:161)

  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy147.queryClientCompanyRightsIssues(Unknown Source)

  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)

  at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.java:87)

  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy145.queryClientCompanyRightsIssues(Unknown Source)

  at org.greenpole.services.clientcompany.rightsissue.RightsService.queryClientCompanyRightsIssues(RightsService.java:164)

  at org.greenpole.controller.clientcompany.RightsIssueController.getClientCompanyRightsIssueList(RightsIssueController.java:134)

  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)

  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)

  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)

  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)

  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)

  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)

  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)

  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)

  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)

  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)

  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)

  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)

  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)

  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)

  at weblogic.websocket.tyrus.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:205)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)

  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)

  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)

  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)

  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

  at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)

  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

  at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)

  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)

  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

  at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)

  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

  at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)

  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)

  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)

  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)

  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

  at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)

  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)

  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

  at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)

  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)

  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

  at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)

  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)

  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)

  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)

  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)

  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)

  at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.__run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java)

  at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)

  at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)

  at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)

  at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)

  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)

  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)

  Number of locked synchronizers = 1

  - java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@706cf33f
```

I read somewhere that JAX-WS isn't thread safe. Am I implementing it wrong, in my case?

Comment: Is the stuck thread the client code above ? i.e. Is the client code running inside Weblogic ?

Comment: Yeah, the stuck thread is the client code above. The client runs inside weblogic and weblogic occasionally breaks down with numerous stuck threads while trying to consume web services

Comment: Weblogic always complains when any transaction takes to long. It is your server that the client is trying to invoke that is misbehaving. I suspect you know that already. Potentially, if to many threads are stuck in the thread pool, Weblogic will not be able to service requests. As for thread safety, I think one "Service service = Service.create(url, qname);" represents on HTTP connection. So don't share your service. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428849/webservice-client-should-i-keep-service-or-port-instance

Comment: Btw the default Time for weblogic to mark a thread as stuck is 10 Minutes (that does not mean it is really stuck, just that it's running for more than 10 minutes)

Comment: rjdkolb, we have logs setup so that whenever requests hit the server we know. In the instance of this stuck thread, no requests comes to the server. So it's not like there's a request and it's taking too long to process. The request isn't coming at all. Meanwhile, the backend servers are still up and the web services are still very much reachable. Usually, when we restart the client application, it's able to access the backend server just fine, then after a while (randomly), a stuck thread appears.

Comment: Slettal, yeah, that's right. Once, I left the stuck thread on and it cleared after 16 mins. But 16 mins is too long for the user to wait. Even 10 mins is too long for the user to wait. And I don't have any operation that takes 10 mins to run. We tested all my web services on SOAP-UI. 2 mins tops, a response comes back

Comment: @Akin_Glen, to be sure that you are getting the same 2 min response time inside Weblogic as you are getting in SoapUI, I suggest you add a simple timer log before and after the webservice call.

Comment: Hi rjdkolb, it's right about the same time recorded by SOUP UI. Just tested it as you suggested. Same with the client too. And that's the thing. I don't know how to induce the stuck thread. At some point, it just pops up. That's what I can't figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this was the network connection between my front-end server and my middleware server (which holds the weblogic server). I got a new server, got VM Ware instead of the Hyper-V I was using, and everything's sorted.

The middleware application is installed on a RHEL (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)